# zf- phpunit - best way to mock / test $this->getRequest()->getParam('controller')

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

phpunit - zend framework

what's the best way to mock / how to test this code 
$this->getRequest()->getParam('controller')
in a controller action helper?

(or any param or that matter as it's all related)

I'm guessing I need to mock the request object and put an expectation on it that method getParam will be found at least once with value controller.

Can someone show me kind of a code example or let me know the best way to do this?  thanks!

Comment: read this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935541/phpunit-test-mvc-controller-with-post-variable#answer-1935553

Comment: Those zf classes have already been unit tested. Trying to do it again is a pain. I found unit testing controllers too much trouble, so I moved all the logic I could into my models and stopped doing it. Improved my code immensely and made unit testing a breeze.

Comment: as part of the method i'm testing, information is set using this so I will not receive code coverage without demonstrating that this can be successfully set in the action helper.  I am expected to maintain 100% code coverage.

Comment: That's a bit short sighted, this is probably the best place to start http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.introduction.html, however I would stick by my original recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to test your controller with certain params - you can do

```
$this->request->setParam($paramName, $paramValue);
```

Comment: in an action helper i need to do this

Comment: $this->_actionController->request->setParam(...) ?