# Mock requests in TYPO3 unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, typo3

Is it possible to mock client (POST or GET) requests in unit testing using the TYPO3 testing framework with phpunit? I'm looking for something like the static::createClient() of Symfony.

UPDATE: Looking at [PHPUnit - test MVC controller with $_POST variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935541/phpunit-test-mvc-controller-with-post-variable) I found the simple solution of just adding to the $_POST array the expected content. Question can be closed.